# 400 error when posting multipart formdata to a WCF service when file reaches certain size

Tags: asp.net, ajax, sharepoint, file-upload, multipartform-data

### Problem:

I am trying to upload a file to a web service using jQuery ajax and the javascript FormData object.  It works fine for files under about 60KB in size.  However, for files above about 70KB I get a "400 bad request" response from the server.  I'm missing something somewhere, but just can't seem to find if.  Any ideas of where I should be looking to find the source of the fault?

- Fails in both a dev environment and in a production environment.
- Tried several different browsers.
- Behavior is independent of the file content.  Binary, text, etc. behave the same.
- Tried using raw XMLHttpRequest instead of jQuery ajax shown below, but encountered the same behavior.

### Server Settings:

- My web service is hosted within a SharePoint 2010 application (ASP.NET IIS .NET 3.5)
- I've checked the httpRuntime setting in the web.config to make sure they are sufficiently big:

  ```
    httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400" executionTimeout="3600"
  ```
- I've checked the requestLimits setting in the applicationHost.config file:

  ```
    requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1024000000"
  ```

### Client Code:

The client code is packing up a FormData object with a file and some data in a json string:

```
formSubmission.prototype.attach = function (servicePath, fileInputElement, successCallback, failedCallback) {
    if (typeof window.FormData === 'undefined') {
        alert(COB.BasicForms.BROWSER_SUPPORT_MSG);
        // More work will have to be done to deal with IE 8 and 9.
        return false;
    }

    var baseServicePath = COB.BasicForms.SERVICE_ADDRESS;

    var formdata = new FormData();
    // This object will be sent as json. Some of its properties
    // are necessary for the server to process the file properly.
    formdata.append('submission', JSON.stringify(this));

    var filename = $(fileInputElement).val().split('\\').pop();
    // We will only accept one file at a time...
    formdata.append('file', fileInputElement.files[0], filename);

    var jqxhr = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: baseServicePath + "//AttachFile",
        data: formdata,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json"
    })

    .done(successCallback)
    .fail(failedCallback);
    return true;
}
```

### Server Code:

As expected the server side code never gets hit when the 400 error is returned.  The server side code does, however, work fine when the file is under 60k.  Here is the basic signature with decorations:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(
       Method = "POST",
       BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
       RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
       ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
       UriTemplate = "AttachFile")]
    FormAttachmentResult AttachFile();
```

Any ideas are most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Sleeping on it always helps.  I forgot to open up the allowed message size in the  section of the web.config.  By default it limits messages to something like 65KB.  Hope this helps someone else when trying to set all the knobs and switches...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731361(v=vs.90).aspx

#### Additional Note:

For SharePoint people, since my service is hosted in vti_bin, modifying the web.config is not possible, since SharePoint automagically hooks up the binding programmatically for services deployed there.  To get around this, a custom service factory class can be used to gain access to the settings programmatically.  See this [post](http://blog.techperspect.com/2013/06/send-large-data-with-sharepoint.html) for more information.